# How does one type an upside-down question mark in IntelliJ on a Mac?

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea

On my Mac, I can usually type an upside-down question mark (¿) by typing Shift + option/alt. However, in IntelliJ, doing this types "public" instead. I could not find any "public" shortcut in the Key Map under Preferences. Short of typing this character in another application, copying it and pasting it into IntelliJ, is there any way around this?

Comment: I also had the same issue(s). You need to find the combination attached to the action that's triggering it in IntelliJ IDEA. Head over `Settings > Keymap` and click on the magnifying glass icon (with three boxes on it) named `Find Actions by Shortcut` – all they way to the right. It should give you the action attached/registered to it.

Comment: If this is a Java question, why aren't you using the unicode of that character instead of the character itself, as in `\u00BF`?

Comment: @x80486 Can you make an Answer of your Comment, to be accepted so we can close this Question?

Comment: @x80486 I already tried this, but got no results.

Comment: @KMan, does it ONLY behaves like that when you are in IntelliJ IDEA, or also for some other applications? I'm thinking that some application(s) might be intercepting that combination also.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I don't suppose there's a simpler way than memorizing the unicode or looking it up each time I need it? Anyway, if you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @x80486 I have not tried this with other applications, but I am only concerned with Intellij IDEA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a key combination attached to that action already in IntelliJ IDEA. That's why you would get a different result than the one expected from the operating system in question.

Head over `Settings > Keymap`. Click on the magnifying glass icon (with three boxes on it) named `Find Actions by Shortcut` – all they way to the right. Once you click on it, execute the key combination that you are looking for, if there is something overriding it, the IDE should give you the action(s) attached/registered to it.

---

**UPDATE**: That combination is attached, by default, to `Code Completion | Cyclic Expand Word (Backward)`. Clear that out and you will be on your way of typing `¿` again in IntelliJ IDEA by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>?</kbd>